# При нажатии появляется блок

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на ссылку появлялся новый блок поверх сайта, а так же чтобы сам сайт в это время затемнялся? если можно, полный пример.

Comment: а что Вы сами пробовали сделать и в чем у Вас возникла сложность?

Comment: это называется модальное окно, лучше укажите какой css фреймверк используете, чтоб на нем добавить пример

Comment: пример на css  - http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/heb785oy/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-то вроде `http://jsfiddle.net/alpha9000/EEgu7/`
Попробуйте средствами jQuery

```
>     $("#block").fadeIn()
>     
>     Появление блока в течении 400 мс
>     
>     $("#block").fadeIn(500)
>     
>     Появление блока в течении 500 мс
>     
>     $("#block").fadeIn("slow")
>     
>     Появление блока в течении 600 мс
```

Comment: нужно появление блока поверх сайта, а не в самом сайте

Comment: @vladislav_zp, так просто создайте блок, который будет на фронтальной части.. z-index: 9999;

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function(){
    if($('.register-w').hasClass('on')){
      $('.register-w').removeClass('on');
    } else {
      $('.register-w').addClass('on');
    }
});

$('.bg').click(function(){
    $('.register-w').removeClass('on');
});
```

```css
.register-w.on .box {
  margin: -50px auto 0;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #000;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 999;
}
.register-w.on .bg {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <p>jskdlfjsldfjslkdfjsdlfkjsdlfk</p>
      <button class="btn">looop</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="register-w">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="bg"></div>
</div>
```

как-то так можно реализовать

Comment: то что нужно. только вот проблема, тут bootstrap подключен, а я пишу на самописе, будут *конфликты* между стилями

Comment: я лишь накидал быстрые чертежи, bootstrap тут только вот <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <p>jskdlfjsldfjslkdfjsdlfkjsdlfk</p>
      <button class="btn">looop</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

Comment: тебе по сути кастомизировать нужно box, а с остальным все ок