# Изменение стилей кнопки в зависимости от её состояния с возвращением в начальный вид

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Имеется кнопка, при нажатии на которую должен меняться её фон (кнопка с выпадающим списком). Задать фон кнопке по нажатию - дело не хитрое, а вот как после этого сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на сторонние области кнопка принимала первоначальный вид?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/579841/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA/579849#579849

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда кликают мимо кнопки, то кнопка теряет фокус и при этом возникает событие `onblur`. А дальше все банально

```js
$('.button').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('selected');
}).blur(function() {
  $(this).removeClass('selected');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Например так:

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  
  var 
    $this = $(this);
  
  if(!$this.hasClass('color')){
    $this.addClass('color');
  }else {
    $this.removeClass('color');
  }
});

$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
    var 
      container = $('.btn');

    if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
        container.removeClass('color');
    }
});
```

```css
.btn {
  background: #ccc;
}

.btn.color {
  background: tomato;
}


/* Доп. стилизация для наглядности */
.btn {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  border: none;  
  margin: 5px auto;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Для button
  <button class="btn">btn</button>

Для a
  <a href="#" class="btn">btn</a>
```